# Resetting CardView's Elevation to the default value (resting elavation)

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles, android-cardview

I want to change a `CardView`'s elevation and reset it later.

Currently, I keep the default value of elevation (called **resting elevation**) as a field value in `onCreateView` of a `Fragment`. Later when I want to reset, set the value with `setCardElevation`.

```
private CardView cardView;
private float restingElevation;
private float pickedUpState = 50.0f;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.table_top);
    restingElevation = cardView.getCardElevation(); // keep the default
    Log.d("elevation", "resting: " + restingElevation);

    return view;
}

private void pickUp() {
    cardView.setCardElevation(pickedUpState);
}

private void rest() {
    cardView.setCardElevation(restingElevation);
}
```

But, I wonder if there are any direct way to set a `CardView`'s elevation to its default value (resting elevation) without keeping the value which has not been changed yet in `onCreateView`. Is there a **resource parameter** (or **style**) for the `android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation` of Material Design theme?

(It seems that the resting elevation of `CardView` is about **2.66** with LogCat. Actually, in the official [Material Design Guide](https://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android-), the resting elevation of Card is indicated between 2dp and 3dp.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have managed to find the default elevation (**resting elevation**) of `CardView`.

```
float elevation = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cardview_default_elevation);
Log.d("elavation", "this is the default: " + elevation);
```

That is **`R.dimen.cardview_default_elevation`**.

Additional inspection:

Actually the `R.dimen.cardview_default_elevation` is just **2dp**, that is described in the official [Material Design Guide](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android). While **`getDimension`** returns the value in **px** which depends on each device. So my device is Nexus7 2012 which has screen density of tvdpi (x1.33 for mdpi) that the returned value is calculated as `2dp x 1.33 = 2.66px`.